# How is DaisyDisk so fast?

Tags: macos, filesystem, disk-space

[DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) scans my Mac's HD blazing fast compared to, say, `du`. I'm wondering what's the trick. I suspect it wouldn't be so fast on non-Mac filesystems, but I haven't tried. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used DaisyDisk, but judging by the video demo on their site, it seems they're using a few tricks to make it fast.

First off, are you sure that `du` is slower? Try running `du / >/dev/null` and see if it is any faster than DaisyDisk .. mind you, the filesystem might have been cached after whichever went first for timing purposes, so the second run will have that advantage.

`du` is pretty quick since it just looks at directory entries and reports path and file sizes. The only way you would know what a file is would be to make a guess by the file extension or look at the file to determine its type (e.g. UNIX "magic" bytes). The file extension route is fast, examining the file is obviously much slower since you have to pull up the file.

With the `du` output, you could quickly determine the view of the top level directories; you can filter that in code and make a representation as DaisyDisk does and just show sized pie slices. If they drill down into the directories (e.g. /Users) then you repeat the process but only focusing on that level. Since DaisyDisk is only showing you the top 10 or 20 space hogs, it doesn't need to go into details to figure out what the smaller files are (notice it conveniently lumps them into "Smaller Files 750MB" or some label). At this point, it still didn't need to dig that deep into the actual files and perhaps if it didn't guess by extension it only had to determine the "magic" of a few large files which goes very quick.

So what we're probably seeing is that it quickly determined the name, path and size of every file on the drive (as `du` can demonstrate), but cleverly only showing the top offenders to help you get to what you're interested in since most people won't use a tool like this to get the nit-picky little files; you'll go to the Finder to examine the files *if you even bother at that level*. There doesn't really appear to be anything special here except that it only needs to examine the file type or content when the user specifically asks for it and the program avoids doing that heavy work most of the time.

So what makes DaisyDisk special versus (say) the free "Grand Perspective" application for OSX? Slick interface for one (I do like the examine file and drag to collect/delete feature), but also I think GP does examine the files while it scans since it shows everything in its graphical view and colors by file type. You could do the color by type mechanism with a `du` approach as well, but you're only guessing based on file extension and/or where you found the file.

All in all, it is a slick application with a clever interface. Why is it fast? Because they appear to have taken short cuts to avoid heavy lifting until it would absolutely be necessary. For me, I'm fine with Grand Perspective :-)

Comment: I suspected they were taking shortcuts, but then again I hadn't accounted for screen output, which is most likely what is taking the most time (I keep forgetting that, damn IO! :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm the developer of DaisyDisk. I'd have to go into lengths to explain how we achieve this on the engineering side, but I can reassure you that the app doesn't make any "shortcuts" or "tricks". The scanning is real and full.

As already mentioned, it's kind of hard to make a precise measurement because of the disk caching. Every experiment will give you a different time, depending on many factors. But it's true that DaisyDisk is by far cry faster than any other disk scanner. This is especially noticeable on SSD drives. Haven't tried to compare it with "du" though.

Comment: I wasn't implying "shortcuts" or "tricks" in any negative sense :-)   What I was referring to is that it didn't seem that DD was scanning the type of every file by examining the contents as it ran; it is just looking at the catalog/dir entries (which is the same thing that `du` does) to build the fast output. Examining type would either have to be quickly assumed by file extension (or where it was found, e.g. iTunes music dir) or examining the file (slower). Seeing how bmike's timing closely matched `du` with DD, I'd assume DD is not examining file content. Either way, nice app and great UI!

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the compliment :) Of course, DaisyDisk doesn't need to scan the contents of files, only the catalogue (name, size) is enough for the task of finding the biggest space hogs. This is exactly what 'du' does too, just less optimally (I guess). I just wanted to note that it's impossible to find the biggest "offenders" until you scan all of them, so there are not really any shortcuts. Also so far we don't use extension (type) information in DaisyDisk, only the size. (Maybe we'll add it later.).

Comment: Thanks @swa16, I'm glad to hear from you :) DD has indeed a great UI, keep up the good work!

Comment: Also, what difference does the "Scan as Administrator" make? It seems to be so much quicker!

Comment: The "Scan as Administrator" command simply includes the restricted folders into the scan. When DaisyDisk encounters a restricted folder, it uses a privileged helper tool to scan it with raised permissions. But the number of such folders is small relative to the overall number of folders, so it should not significantly affect the time of scanning.

Comment: But when you have already scanned a disk in normal mode, you can select "Quick Rescan as Administrator" command, then only the (previously skipped) restricted folders will be scanned. This is indeed much faster than full disk rescan as Administrator (or initial Scan as Administrator).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to measure any large difference in `du` or DaisyDisk other than the native app is slower in some cases than the command line tool.

```
time du ~ > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The first run of `du` was 0m7.947s and the second was 0m5.465s and DaisyDisk was about 8 seconds with a stopwatch both times.

My guess is you are seeing delays due to screen output of the command line tools measuring more of the disk. Are you using DaisyDisk to scan as administrator?

Comment: Indeed, that is likely to be the answer. Plus, what @bjb said :)

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed that `du` uses `getattrlist()` in a single threaded mode. I had found some code that apple open sourced sometime back with the High Sierra release. Daisydisk probably uses `getattrlistbulk()` with multiple threads, since I noticed a more even CPU core usage.

On my Mac, daisydisk is always 2x - 3x faster than `du`. I have tested this with my home folder of 100G, 20K directories, 350K files. The file system does some caching, so it is better to test this on a cold system, or with a large directory to reduce the caching benefits.

I found this code snippet helpful for `getattrlistbulk` -
https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/526248/A-sample-on-how-to-properly-use-getattrl

This snippet still uses a single thread, and the thread was IO bound, my CPU usage was around 35% only. If you somehow spread the work onto multiple threads, I do expect this to be super fast.

Comment: Excellent answer and API information. I’m finding **ncdu** pleasantly fast as well. Be sure to read all the comments form the developer of DaisyDisk - pretty cool details https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263198/5472